# Sporadic 503s from specified ports

Tags: docker, rancher

I've been working on using Rancher for manager our dashboard applications, part of this has involved exposing multiple kibana containers from the same port, and one kibana 3 container exposing on port 80.

I want to therefore send requests on specified ports: 5602, 5603, 5604 to specific containers, so I setup the following docker-compose.yml config:

```
kibana:
  image: rancher/load-balancer-service
  ports:
  - 5602:5602
  - 5603:5603
  - 5604:5604
  links:
  - kibana3:kibana3
  - kibana4-logging:kibana4-logging
  - kibana4-metrics:kibana4-metrics
  labels:
    io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.kibana3: 5602=80
    io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.kibana4-logging: 5603=5601
    io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.kibana4-metrics: 5604=5601
```

Everything works as expected, but I get sporadic 503's.  When I go into the container and look at the haproxy.cfg I see:

```
frontend d898fb95-ec51-4c73-bdaa-cc0435d8572a_5603_frontend
        bind *:5603
        mode http

        default_backend d898fb95-ec51-4c73-bdaa-cc0435d8572a_5603_2_backend

backend d898fb95-ec51-4c73-bdaa-cc0435d8572a_5603_2_backend
        mode http
        timeout check 2000
        option httpchk GET /status HTTP/1.1
        server cbc23ed9-a13a-4546-9001-a82220221513 10.42.60.179:5603 check port 5601 inter 2000 rise 2 fall 3
        server 851bdb7d-1f6b-4f61-b454-1e910d5d1490 10.42.113.167:5603
        server 215403bb-8cbb-4ff0-b868-6586a8941267 10.42.85.7:5601
```

The IPs listed are all three Kibana containers, the first container has a health check has it, but none of the others do (kibana3/kibana4.1 dont have a status endpoint).  My understanding of the docker-compose config is it should have only the one server per backend, but all three appear to be listed, I assume this is in part down to the sporadic 503s, and removing this manually and restarting the haproxy service does seem to solve the problem.

I am configuring the load balancer incorrectly or is this worth raising as a Github issue with Rancher?

Comment: Which rancher server release? Try the latest one, currently, it is v1.0.0, GA release.

Comment: Cheers for the response, I'm on v1.0.0 GA, I'm going to post the answer I got off the Rancher forum as it appears the advanced routing is only for hostname mapping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted on the Rancher forums as that was suggested from Rancher Labs on twitter: https://forums.rancher.com/t/load-balancer-sporadic-503s-with-multiple-port-bindings/2358

Someone from rancher posted a link to a github issue which was similar to what I was experiencing: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/2475

In summary, the load balancers will rotate through all matching backends, there is a work around involving "dummy" domains, which I've confirmed with my configuration does work, even if it is slightly inelegant.

```
labels:
  # Create a rule that forces all traffic to redis at port 3000 to have a hostname of bogus.com
  # This eliminates any traffic from port 3000 to be directed to redis
  io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.conf/redis: bogus.com:3000
 # Create a rule that forces all traffic to api at port 6379 to have a hostname of bogus.com
  # This eliminates any traffic from port 6379 to be directed to api
  io.rancher.loadbalancer.target.conf/api: bogus.com:6379
```

(^^ Copied from rancher github issue, not my workaround)

I'm going to see how easy it would be to route via port and raise a PR/Github issue as I think it's a valid usecase for an LB in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you are using the port initially exposed on the docker container. For some reason, if you bind it to a different port, HAProxy fails to work. If you are using a container from DockerHub that is using a port already taken on your system, you may have to rebuild that docker container to use a different port by routing it through a proxy like nginx.